# What is the probability that two or more cars will collide with each other?

Tags: probability, statistics, recreational-mathematics

I was asked this question in an interview.

> If there are four cars parked, one on each corner of a rectangular parking space, each car can move in either direction, what is the probability that two or more cars will collide with each other?

My idea is if $4$ cars are on the corners then we have to find if $2$ or more cars move in the same direction. But what are the total number of directions a car can move to.

Need help guys with mathematical solution.

Comment: A car can move forward or backward, from what I understand (impossible for it to move sideways)

Comment: I assume they are confined to the borders of the rectangle?  If so, the only way to avoid a collision is for all of them to choose the same direction (either clockwise or counterclockwise).

Comment: Each car can choose two directions independently. Now of all the possible outcomes, the only way they do not collide when they are all moving in the same direction (how many ways?)

Comment: Why should the collide at all? Just because they _can_  move doesn't mean they move randomly, right?

Comment: The trick part is they can move in either direction. Does that mean they have 3 possible directions they can move if they are in rectangular spot.

Comment: Actually I got it now. The only way to have no collisions is for all cars to go clockwise, or all go counterclockwise. Any of the other 14 possibilities will lead to a collision. Thanks @lulu

Comment: In my experience, the meta-test is to see if the applicant knows to ask for clarifications. :) This question as stated is so unclear, and can be interpreted in so many ways, that if the applicant did not ask for clarifications and dived in right away that might be considered a negative.  (However, my observation might only apply to certain fields / cultures, sorry.)